# Prefixing part and chapter names in table of contents in LaTeX report

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

I have a LaTeX report as follows:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\appendix
\bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Name of appendix}
\chapter{Name of appendix}

\end{document}
```

Which produces a .pdf file as with the contents page follows:

[image]

This is fine but can the words Part, Chapter and Appendix be used as prefixes to the relevant items in the contents? I mean that a Part III in the graphic below might read:

> Part III Name of part
>
> Chapter 4 Name of chapter

I have tried `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Chapter\Alph{chapter}}` but it overwrites part of the actual chapter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I've patched the start of the `appendices` environment to place some content into the ToC file as per your requirement.

Adjustments are made to `\cftpartpresnum` (inserted *before* the `\part` number) and `\cftchappresnum` (inserted *before* the `\chapter` number). Since the appendices are set differently, `Appendices` is inserted manually as a `\part`-like entry.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}%
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\usepackage{bookmark}%

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{65pt}%

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\partname\hspace{10pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\hspace{5pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\hspace{5pt}}

\let\oldappendices\appendices
\renewcommand{\appendices}{%
  \oldappendices
  \bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftpartpresnum{}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{}%
    \protect\setlength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{15pt}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Some content related to the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\part{Second part}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}

\part{Third part}
\chapter{Fifth chapter}

\part{Fourth part}
\chapter{Sixth chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}
\chapter{Second appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the 'prefixes' for toc entries is best done with the various `\cftX....` commands from the `tocloft` package.

`\cftchappresnum` is used to set `Chapter` before the chapter number entries, followed by some spacing, which should be changed to 'personal taste'
The some is done with `\cftpartpresnum`.

As well, the space for the the number width is changed, this depends on personal settings `\cftchaptnumwidth`.

In my personal view, the chapters should be indented, but I commented it out. Change at will `\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{...}` so some appropiate value.

---

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}%
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\usepackage{bookmark}%

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\cftpartfont\appendixname}%

%\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{20pt}%
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{60pt}%

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\hspace{5pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\hspace{5pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\partname\hspace{10pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\part{Name of part}
\chapter{Name of chapter}

\begin{appendices}%
\bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
%\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Name of appendix}
\chapter{Name of appendix}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian. This is very close to what I want. But do you know if it's possible to  but place the heading 'Appendices' above the appendices, and if the Chapter X be removed from the individual appendix headings?

Comment: @MrMorgan: Opps,sorry, forget that ;-) I will try immediately